# Normalized likelihoods

Tags: logistic, binary-data, aic, likelihood-ratio, ordered-logit

AIC (BIC) model selection methods are widely used. These methods can select non-nested models unlike likelihood ratio type selection that requires model to be nested.  The AIC has definition $\text{AIC}=-2\text{log}L+2V$  where $L$ is the likelihood of the model and $V$ is the effective number of paramters in that model.

Take for instance making a decision whether to use a binary or an ordinal logistic regression model.

You receive the response variable in an ordinal form with labels say $1,2,3 $. But it is required from you to predict observations with label $\{1,2\}$ as one group and observations with label  $3$ as another.  Therefore you have two ways to go

1)Group the data into two groups with labels $0$ for observation with labels $\{1,2\}$ and $1$ for for observations with label $3$ and use a binary logistic model.

2)Use the original $3$ labels $1,2,3$ in an ordinal logistic regression model and end up using the boundary from your ordinal model that separates observations with labels $2$ from observations with labels $3$. Since it is an ordinal model it will automatically be the boundary that separates group $\{1,2\}$ from group $3$

I will represent the two scenarios[image: Blue and red lines are boundries from an ordinal model, black line is the boundry from a binary model] with plots.

Blue and red lines are boundaries from an ordinal model, black line is the boundary from a binary model. Black points are labelled with 1, red points 2 and blue points 3. Therefore as described above I am either using the blue line when I choose to use an ordinal model or the black line when I choose to use the binary model.

Using the AIC to choose either the binary or the ordinal model is possible. But the two models differ in two things.

1) Likelihood scale
2) Parameter scale.

Is there a  normalization that can be done so that the two models can be compared in terms of their AICs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare AICs directly simply because the ordinal response and the binary response are not the same. Even a simple log transformation of (continuous) response renders AICs non-comparable. I don't think there is a trick that can make AICs comparable in this case.

As far as model selection, I think you should stick with the binary model. When you switch from binary to ordinal, you add extra parameters that are spent on discriminating between 1 and 2, which is absolutely beside your goal. Essentially, you lower your observation/parameter ratio for nothing. In any case, it's a good idea to compare the models directly via out-of-sample ROC.

Comment: Remember that efficiency of parameters is increased as you move from  a binary to a proportional odds model where both models have a good GOF. Therefore you concentrating on only the observation/parameter ratio is not enough. Therefore instead of asserting intuitively, an analytic approach to the problem is all I ask for. The AICs are not comparable. My thoughts were whether,  is it possible to have a universal scale for , likehoods and effective number of parameters?. I have seen papers of normalised likelihoods(NML). [link] (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022249605000532)

Comment: Why do you want to use in-sample statistics at all, especially in such non-trivial case? Why not get out-of-sample ROC?

Comment: Indeed you are right ... but then in parameter estimation we must use MLEs? No matter the out sample judgement likelihoods  must in some way be used...

Comment: You use MLE to estimate parameters in the model (in sample), then in order to choose the best model you use test the fitted models out-of-sample by measuring ROC area.